# MySQLi equivalent of mysql_result()?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm porting some old PHP code from mysql to MySQLi, and I've ran into a minor snag.

Is there no equivalent to the old `mysql_result()` function?

I know `mysql_result()` is slower than the other functions when you're working with more than 1 row, but a lot of the time I have only 1 result and 1 field. Using it lets me condense 4 lines into 1.

Old code:

```
if ($r && mysql_num_rows($r))  
    $blarg = mysql_result($r, 0, 'blah');
```

Desired code:

```
if ($r && $r->num_rows)  
    $blarg = $r->result(0, 'blah');
```

But there is no such thing. :(

Is there something I'm missing? Or am I going to have to suck it up and make everything:

```
if ($r && $r->num_rows)  
{  
    $row = $r->fetch_assoc();  
    $blarg = $row['blah'];  
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

PHP 5.4 now supports [function array dereferencing](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) and 7.0 supports a  [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php), which means you can simply do this:

```
$value = $r->fetch_assoc()['blah'] ?? false;
```

or even more generic variant where you don't need to supply the column name,

```
$value = $r->fetch_row()[0] ?? false;
```

note that you don't even need the `if ($r && $r->num_rows)` condition.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thanks. I think the answer looks better now and the original meaning was retained. That's better than changing the meaning of the top answer. I also removed some comments from this page, let me know if I need to remove more.

Answer (score 42):

The following function fully replicates the `mysql_result()` function, and returns `false` when you are out-of-bounds on your request (empty result, no row of that number, no column of that number). It does have the added benefit that, if you don't specify the row, it assumes 0,0 (one less value to be passed). The function allows for the numerical offset of the field ***or the field name.***

```
function mysqli_result($res,$row=0,$col=0){ 
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($res); 
    if ($numrows && $row <= ($numrows-1) && $row >=0){
        mysqli_data_seek($res,$row);
        $resrow = (is_numeric($col)) ? mysqli_fetch_row($res) : mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
        if (isset($resrow[$col])){
            return $resrow[$col];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I believe there is a bug in this function, if (isset($resrow[$col])){     should be if    (array_key_exists($col, $resrow)){ otherwise it returns false for null results

Comment: This function does not fully implement mysql_result() as mysql_result() allows the $col to be an integer, or a string containing the field name.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by fetching an object instead of an array.

```
$mysqli->query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE userid = 'foo'")->fetch_object()->email;
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can always shorten it to something like this:

```
if ($r && $r->num_rows)
    list($blarg) = $r->fetch_row();
```

But that might be as good as you're going to get.

Answer (score 2):

```
function db_result($result,$row,$field) { 
  if($result->num_rows==0) return 'unknown'; 
  $result->data_seek($row);
  $ceva=$result->fetch_assoc(); 
  $rasp=$ceva[$field]; 
  return $rasp; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add this line to [Cris' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3779460/) in order to be able to get a result by both doing `db_result('mytable.myfield)` and `db_result('myfield')` since it is the default behavior of the original `mysql_result` function.

```
function db_result($result,$row,$field) { 
    if($result->num_rows==0) return 'unknown'; 
    $result->data_seek($row);
    $ceva=$result->fetch_assoc(); 
    return (isset($ceva[$field])?$ceva[$field]
        :(strpos($field,'.')?$ceva[substr($field,strrpos($field,'.')+1)]:'')); 
}
```

Comment: I just realized that this only works if you have only one field named 'myfield' in your request. I you have 2 tables with a field called 'myfield' db_result('table1.myField') and db_result('table2.myField') will have the same value even if the values are different in the db row. The old mysql_result function were doing the job right, so it's not exactly the same behavior.

Answer (score -1):

I use the following function to replace mysql_result()

```
function mysqli_result($result, $iRow, $field = 0)
{
    if(!mysqli_data_seek($result, $iRow))
        return false;
    if(!($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)))
        return false;
    if(!array_key_exists($field, $row))
        return false;
    return $row[$field];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using a custom function using procedural style:

```
function mysqli_result($res, $row, $field=0) {
    mysqli_data_seek($res, $row);
    return mysqli_fetch_array($res)[$field];
}
```

Reference: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/change-mysql-result-to-mysqli/190972/6

Answer (score -1):

**You don't need `mysql_result()` or any similar function.**

If you would like to access any column from any row in the result set, the best way is to fetch all into an array using [`mysqli_fetch_all()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php).

```
$data = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_BOTH);
$var1 = $data[0]['column']; // column from the first row
$var2 = $data[1][2]; // third column from the second row
```

To prevent access to non-existent values, you can use the null-coalesce operator and provide default value. e.g. `$data[1][2] ?? null;`.

As of PHP 8.1, mysqli also offers method called [`fetch_column()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-column.php). You can use it if you only want to fetch a single value from the result.

```
$value = $mysqli->query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE userid = 'foo'")->fetch_column(0);
```

Answer (score -2):

If you select only ONE field in the query and you only expect a single returned data of a selected field, then this works:

```
function mysqli_datum($result)
{
    if ($result->num_rows == 0)
        return;
    $result->data_seek(0);
    $row=$result->fetch_row();     
    return $row[0];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's an adaptation of Mario Lurig's answer using a `mysqli_result` object instead of the procedural version of `mysqli`.

```
/**
 * Accepts int column index or column name.
 *
 * @param mysqli_result $result
 * @param int $row
 * @param int|string $col
 * @return bool
 */
function resultMysqli(mysqli_result $result,$row=0,$col=0) { 
    //PHP7 $row can use "int" type hint in signature
    $row = (int)$row; // PHP5 - cast to int
    if(!is_numeric($col) ) { // cast to string or int
        $col = (string)$col;
    } else {
        $col = (int)$col;
    }
    $numrows = $result->num_rows;
    if ($numrows && $row <= ($numrows-1) && $row >=0) {
        $result->data_seek($row);
        $resrow = (is_numeric($col)) ? $result->fetch_row() : $result->fetch_assoc();
        if (isset($resrow[$col])){
            return $resrow[$col];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

This is a good answer, from http://php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-result.php

```
<?php
function mysqli_result($result,$row,$field=0) {
    if ($result===false) return false;
    if ($row>=mysqli_num_rows($result)) return false;
    if (is_string($field) && !(strpos($field,".")===false)) {
        $t_field=explode(".",$field);
        $field=-1;
        $t_fields=mysqli_fetch_fields($result);
        for ($id=0;$id<mysqli_num_fields($result);$id++) {
            if ($t_fields[$id]->table==$t_field[0] && $t_fields[$id]->name==$t_field[1]) {
                $field=$id;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ($field==-1) return false;
    }
    mysqli_data_seek($result,$row);
    $line=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    return isset($line[$field])?$line[$field]:false;
}
?>
```

Comment: This might not be the best solution regarding performance, but it's the only working answer for queries using the table name as prefix for every field queried, +1.