# What is PHP Excel worksheet limit? How to di switch PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter?

Tags: php, excel

How can I switch **PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter** from exce5 to Excel2007 in a php project.
What all installations and modifications I need to do?

Thanks.....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mysql to mysqli php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551469/mysql-to-mysqli-php)

Answer (score 0):

PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter('Excel2007');