# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_result() in

Tags: mysql

I am getting this error while changing from **mysql_result** to **mysqli_result**

```
function f_exists($f_uname) {
     $f_uname = sanitize($f_uname);
     $conn = @mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','swift') or die($connect_error);
     $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT COUNT(`f_id`) FROM `flight_users` WHERE `f_uname`= '$f_uname'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));


    //here is the problem
    return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
```

}

Comment: You can't mix and match `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` apis. Are you using PHP 7? If so the `mysql_*` api has been completely removed.

Comment: Could I solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not mix `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*`. Furthermore you cannot use `mysql_result` in the way you use it with `mysql_*`. Just replace this

```
return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
```

with the following:

```
if ($query && mysqli_num_rows($query) == 1) {  
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc()['count_val'];  
}
```

Therefore you need to use an alias for your count value in your statement, which you should always do: `SELECT COUNT(f_id) as count_val ...`

See this topic for more information about an equivalent to the `mysql_result` in `mysql_*`: [MySQLi equivalent of mysql_result()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089590/mysqli-equivalent-of-mysql-result)