# Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects at most 2 parameters in PHP

Tags: php, for-loop, mysqli, pagination

I tried to create pagination with database iteration. This is my code so far.

```
$per_page = 5;
$result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM inquiries");
$total_records = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $per_page);

if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $show_page = $_GET['page'];
    if ($show_page > 0 && $show_page <= $total_pages) {
        $start = ($show_page - 1) * $per_page;
        $end = $start + $per_page;
    } else {
        $start = 0;
        $end = $per_page;
    }
} else {
    $start = 0;
    $end = $per_page;
}
$page = intval($_GET['page']);

$tpages=$total_pages;
if ($page <= 0)
    $page = 1;
for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++) {
    if ($i == $total_records) {
        break;
    }
    echo mysqli_fetch_array($result,$i,'message');
```

that. Since it makes following error.

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given in..

Can someone help me to solve this error.

Comment: Do the pagination with `LIMIT start, count` in the query.

Comment: Also, consider using `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())`

Comment: But I want to do it through 'for' loop. Otherwise pagination will not work

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use `mysqli_fetch_array()` as a replacement for `mysql_result()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089590/mysqli-equivalent-of-mysql-result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` with limit at first query then `SELECT FOUND_ROWS();` as total count.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS, Id, Name FROM my_table WHERE <give your condition> LIMIT 0, 10;

# Find total rows
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Comment: use echo mysqli_fetch_array($result); in replace of echo mysqli_fetch_array($result,$i,'message');

Comment: But then what happen to $i? Can you please explain that what exactly done through 'SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS'?

Comment: Handle the OFFSET by caluculation by looping like 
Select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS uid, name users  ORDER BY uid desc LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0 
Select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS uid, name users  ORDER BY uid desc LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5 
Select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS uid, name users  ORDER BY uid desc LIMIT 5 OFFSET 15 
and do the total count like $count = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT FOUND_ROWS()";
I hope it does make sense. code is not tested.

Comment: Yes it helpful. Thank you